# Uploading new file changes all uploaded files to new file for entire entry

Tags: grid, fieldtype, bug

My site (3.4.0) has 2 separate channels with this issue, the only channels with multiple File fields right now. When creating a new entry in either channel, the last file I upload in any File field replaces all other File fields.

So after I've added the image file in the image field in the 1st channel, I upload an audio file from a different file upload folder in an "audio" File field. When I do this, it replaces the file for the image field also with the audio file, so both fields now have the audio file (regardless if the image field could accept the filetype). If I do it in reverse order, both fields will have the image file.

Another channel has a Grid field, in which one can choose multiple different files and file types for up to 8 grid entries. The same thing occurs: after I've uploaded/chosen 1 file, the second file I upload replaces both so I have duplicates. This continues such that the last file I choose will replace all the others for up to 8 duplicates. Editing / replacing any file while still creating a New Entry will have the same result, all files will be changed at once.

The only work-around I have at the moment is, after saving the New Entry, if I edit that entry I can change any file without it changing all the others. But this isn't user-friendly, I don't want to tell all users they have to save their entry and then edit it to make multiple files work. Please help if you know what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to a [File Picker bug](https://expressionengine.com/support/bugs/22018/) which was fixed in 3.4.2. Update your install and it should resolve.